# reset MainWindow layout Pyqt5

Tags: layout, pyqt5, refresh, mainwindow

I am creating a simple PyQt GUI that initially shows a login window. Upon successful login, the MainWindow is supposed to refresh and change the MainWindow layout.
The approach I used is creating two layouts (loginLayout and mainLayout). The initial layout is set to loginLayout with

```
self.view.setLayout(loginLayout)
self.setCentralWidget(self.view)
```

then upon successful login, the `handle_login` function would change the MainWindow layout to mainLayout:

```
self.view.setLayout(mainLayout)
self.setCentralWidget(self.view)
```

Essentially, changing the centralWidget of MainWindow.

For days I could not get this to work. The MainWindow layout would not refresh after a successful login.

Below are my `MainWindow class` and `main.py`

**MainWindow Class:**

```py
import glowButton as custom
from Login_class import *
from binnerWidget import *

WINDOW_SIZE = 1000, 700

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    LOGIN_CODE = 0

    # constructor for MainWindow class
    def __init__(self):
        # calls the constructor of the parent class 'QMainWindow' using 'super'
        # ensures the initialization of the parent class before customization
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        # create dragView object which is a child widget of "MainWindow"
        # self here is the current MainWindow object, and is passed in dragView constructor
        self.view = custom.dragView(self)
        # set up (calls/initializes) MainWindows's user interface attributes
        self.initUI()

    # set up the initial window UI
    def initUI(self):
        # set position to 300, 300, and size of window, * to unpack tuple
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, *WINDOW_SIZE)
        # set window title
        self.setWindowTitle('PSE Piezometer Limits')
        # set the minimum height and width of the window (when resizing)
        self.setMinimumHeight(550)
        self.setMinimumWidth(950)
        # set window flags (need understand more)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.Window | Qt.FramelessWindowHint)  # removes window decorations (ex: border, buttons...)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)  # sets window background semi-translucent

        # loginLayout
        loginLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.loginWidget = Login(self)
        self.BannerWidget = Banner(self)
        loginLayout.addWidget(self.BannerWidget)
        # loginLayout.setStretchFactor(bannerLayout, 0)  # so bannerLayout would stay on top of the MainWindow
        loginLayout.addWidget(self.loginWidget)
        
        # mainLayout
        self.mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(Banner(self)) #, alignment=Qt.AlignTop)
        # self.mainLayout.setStretchFactor(bannerLayout, 0)  # so bannerLayout would stay on top of the MainWindow
        self.mainLayout.addStretch(1)

        self.status = QLabel()

        # set MainWindow loginLayout and Initially, show the login layout
        self.view.setLayout(loginLayout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.view)

        self.loginWidget.login_button.clicked.connect(self.handle_login)


    def handle_login(self):
        # Implement your login logic here
        username = self.loginWidget.username_edit.text()
        password = self.loginWidget.password_edit.text()

        # For simplicity, let's assume login is successful if username and password are not empty
        login_successful = bool(username and password)

        if login_successful:
            self.LOGIN_CODE = 1
            self.update_status("Login successful!", "green")
            self.show_main_content()
        else:
            self.LOGIN_CODE = -1
            QMessageBox.warning(self, 'Login Failed', 'Invalid username or password. Please try again.')

    def show_main_content(self):
        # Switch to the main content layout
        self.view.setLayout(self.mainLayout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.view)


    def update_status(self, text, color):
        self.status.setStyleSheet("color: {}".format(color))
        self.status.setText(text)

    def min_window(self):
        self.setWindowState(Qt.WindowMinimized)


    def closeEvent(self, event):
        try:
            if hasattr(self, "confWindow"):
                self.confWindow.close()
            super(QMainWindow, self).closeEvent(event)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

**main.py:**

```py
# Press the green button in the gutter to run the script.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # initialize QApplication object, app is the application itself
    app = QApplication([])
    # process any pending events while splashScreen is displayed
    app.processEvents()
    # create main window
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Upon googling, I have tried two approaches:

1. used self.refresh() and self.update() inside handle_login function to delete the layout of the widget first, then add a new layout. This approach did nothing.
2. tried using QStackedLayout, but it only takes QWidget object rather than layout objects. I would like to stack my two layouts (loginLayout and mainLayout) so I could toggle between them later.

Comment: You cannot set a layout on a widget if one already exists (check the debug output, or run the program in a terminal or prompt as some IDEs don't always show external module output, and you'll see an error about that). In any case, it doesn't make a lot of sense to change the layout of an existing widget: use QStackedWidget as a central widget instead, and switch between its internal "pages". Also: 1. Qt already provides the `showMinimized()` function, don't use window states unless you really know what you're doing; 2. avoid unnecessary comments for code that already is self explanatory.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yea, I am very new to Pyqt so I try to comment everything out. I had tried to use QStackedWidget, but it only takes QWidget but not a Layout Object. So in this case how can I modify my two layouts to be added to QStackedLayout?

Comment: QStackedWidget is based on QStackedLayout, which is the only Qt layout that doesn't allow direct children layouts. The solution, though, is quite simple: create a separate basic QWidget for each of those layouts, and add them to QStackedWidget instead. Note that commenting everything doesn't really help you in the end, especially if it's redundant and done for almost all functions: take the line `self.setWindowTitle('PSE Piezometer Limits')`, which you commented with the exact same words of the function, "set window title". Comments should only be used when code isn't self-explanatory enough.

Comment: @musicamante thanks for your answer, I will try this out!